# How to Change Cell's Color Based on text in Asp.net Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am working on an attendance portal[image]

I want to change the cell color based on the text in cell, like if a cell contain "P" then its background color must be green and for "A" it must be Red.
How to achieve this?

Comment: How are you binding data to gridview, you could use template

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using OnRowDataBound

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[3];
        string data = cell.Text;
        if (data == "A")
        {
            cell.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else if (data == "P")
        {
            cell.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Here you could iterate for all the cells and reuse the same code for all 31 days

Answer (score 0):

Hello here's a way to do this :

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[1];
        int quantity = int.Parse(cell.Text);
        if (quantity == 0)
        {
            cell.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        if (quantity > 0 && quantity <= 50)
        {
            cell.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
        if (quantity > 50 && quantity <= 100)
        {
            cell.BackColor = Color.Orange;
        }
    }
}
```

In this exemple you only check the second cell (e.Row.Cells[2]) 
you could make a for loop for your own exemple like this :

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
          for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
          {
              
              TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[i];

              int quantity = int.Parse(cell.Text);
              if (quantity == 0)
              {
                  cell.BackColor = Color.Red;
              }
              if (quantity > 0 && quantity <= 50)
              {
                  cell.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
              }
              if (quantity > 50 && quantity <= 100)
              {
                  cell.BackColor = Color.Orange;
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I also had used almost same code as yours. You can also check my code. Can you tell me how to add weekends and holidays to the above grid?

Comment: I don't know where are the weekends on in your grid and how they are represented in the model you bind to grid. Can you give me details please ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i have done to solve this:

```
    protected void Grid1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
    
        
          if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
          {
    
          int colCount = e.Row.Cells.Count;
          for (int i = 2; i < colCount; i++)
           {
              if (e.Row.Cells[i].Text == "A")
              {
                e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                e.Row.Cells[i].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
              }
              if (e.Row.Cells[i].Text == "P")
              {
                e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                e.Row.Cells[i].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
              }
           }
          }
    }
```